# merging array of char is reversing the order

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have written a simple program to slip bit positions in an integer like 73. When I am converting array back to string, it seems the order of bits are reversing. I should be getting 11, my answer is coming out wrong as 104. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
public class P5_2 {


public static int myswap(int x, int i, int j)
{
    String xStr = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
    char[] arr = xStr.toCharArray();

    System.out.println(arr);

    char temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;


    xStr = new String(arr);

    //it seems it is joining the char array from LSB to MSB side, hence flipping !! why

    System.out.println(xStr);

    x = Integer.parseInt(xStr, 2);

    return x;


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int x = 73;
    int n;
    int i = 6;
    int j = 1;

    n = myswap(x, i, j);


    System.out.print(n);
}
}
```

Comment: Are to trying reverse the entire binary bits ?

    char temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;

What does this code supposed to mean .here why you are only swapping i-th index with j-th index ? What do you mean by "to slip bit positions in an integer " ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually bits in a binary number representation are numbered from right to left, in order from least significant to most signifant.

For example the number 73 in binary:

```
binary digits: 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
bit number:    6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

However, when you convert to a binary string such as with `toBinaryString()`, the most significant digit is output first because the digits in the string are stored from left to right. For example the string "10001001":

```
char values: "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1"
array index:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

To swap bits 1 and 6 of the original number, you need to swap elements 5 and 0 of the char array. This will give you the string "0001011" which parses to 11. Swapping elements 1 and 6 will give you the string "1101000" which is 104.

So you just need to reverse the order of the indices based on length of the string:

```
String xStr = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
i = (xStr.length() - 1) - i;
j = (xStr.length() - 1) - j;
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use strings at all, you can swap the bits using [bit-manipulation](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR):

```
public static int myswap(int x, int i, int j)
{
    // b is 1 if the bits are different (xor), 0 if not
    int b = ((x >> i) ^ (x >> j)) & 1;
    // flip the bits if they are different
    return x ^ ((b << i) | (b << j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the ParseInt is a bit tricky one. Please refer more Parse Int Radix - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_parseint_radix.htm

```
  public class P5_2 {

    public static int myswap(int x, int i, int j)
    {
    String xStr = Integer.toBinaryString(x);

    System.out.println("xStr : "+xStr);
    char[] arr = xStr.toCharArray();


    char temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;


    xStr = new String(arr);

    //it seems it is joining the char array from LSB to MSB side, hence flipping !! why

    System.out.println(xStr);

    x= Integer.parseInt( xStr.substring(0, 2) );

   // x = Integer.parseInt(xStr, 2);

    return x;


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int x = 73;
    int n;
    int i = 6;
    int j = 1;

    n = myswap(x, i, j);


    System.out.print(n);
}
  }
```

Comment: This code is not correct. You are simply converting the String "11" to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, arrays are zero based. When you are asking `swap` to flip the 6th bit with the 1st bit in the number 73, you were actually having swap flip the 2nd and the 7th bit.

To fix this, just have the swap method subtract both the i and j by 1 and it will work as expected:

```
public static int myswap(int x, int i, int j)
{
    i = i - 1;
    j = j - 1;

    // rest of code...
}
```